# Lookup filters are not working properly for custom field in account

Tags: community, administration, account

In Opportunity related account object, Account is a lookup field. In Account, Rep/agent number is a custom field. Whenever I click account lookup, and enter Rep/agent number, and then click Apply filters, it is not showing any account name even though there are existing accounts with the Rep/agent number.

Why these filters are not working properly? For reference i am attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You have to select the Search All Fields radio option in the search dialog...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that under the search bar you can either search by Name or by All Fields. Make sure you select All Fields if you want to search by a custom field value.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer.Yes i selected All fields but it didnt search properly.Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post an updated screenshot of what you tried? @Swetha